# Unable to load images dynamically in react app

Tags: reactjs

I have this component :-

```
const CollectionItem = ({ item }) => (
    <div className='collection-item'>
        <div
            className='image'
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${item.imageUrl})`
            }} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

my images urls are like ../../assets/images/imageName.jpg

i have tried loading a an image in the css file associated with this component with this exact url. It is working with css, but not in jsx. Please help.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, how you load images in react is to import the image from the specified folder (webpack converts it into the correct source behind the scenes), and then to use that imported variable as the `src` of the image.

```
import imgSource from "../../assets/images/imageName.jpg";

const CollectionItem = ({ item }) => (
    <div className='collection-item'>
        <div
            className='image'
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${imgSource})`
            }} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

**EDIT**
In the cases where the import depends upon the props, you could simple dynamically import the image within the function itself:

```
const CollectionItem = ({ item }) => (
    import imgSource from `${item.imageUrl}`;
    <div className='collection-item'>
        <div
            className='image'
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${imgSource})`
            }} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

In the case that it does not work, you can try using `require` instead

```
const imgSource = require(item.imageUrl);
```

Comment: then how would i make my import dynamic?

Comment: you could just use dynamic imports, I will edit my answer with it

Comment: the require syntax did it!!!  thank you so much. i wish i could upvote more than once