# Change text when different images are clicked in React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, onclick

**My goal is to have 3 different images and when they are clicked, each image will change the text displayed.** My problem is that when each image is clicked, it still displays the image path in the first list item, like the screenshot below("../../img/shield.png"). How can I prevent this from showing?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./UserRoles.css";
import shield from "../../img/shield.png"
import sword from "../../img/sword.png"
import staff from "../../img/staff.png"
```

```
const roles = [
  [
     shield,
    "Term1",
    "Description1",
  ],
  [
     sword,
    "Term2",
    "Description2",
  ],
  [
     staff,
    "Term3",
    "Description3",
  ],
];
```

```
const UserRoles = () => {
  const [clickedText, setClickedText] = useState([]);

  var handleClick = (index) => {
    setClickedText(roles[index]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* map through texts array */}
      {roles.map((role, index) => (
        <img src={roles[index][0]} key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(index)} />
      ))}

      <ul>
        {clickedText.map((t, index) => (
          <ul>
            <li key={index}>{t}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserRoles;
```

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is, could you clarify it in both the title and the body of this question?

Comment: I guess it is more of a problem of how to make this work. I am not sure what I should be asking, only what my intention is.  With what I have written so far, how would I make my goal work ? My brain tells me my image paths aren't working so I should look at that first. so far I realize I have arrays inside of an array so I need to put {roles[0][0]} instead of just {role}. so I need to update that at least

Comment: I think you are saying that your image paths are not working, is that what you need to fix?

Comment: If this is an issue with images only then it seems the question could be considered as a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849999/how-to-load-images-in-react

Comment: Possibly, not sure that will fix the entire problem but I think that is a part of it yes. the link is useful but I am trying to put images into an array above. Can I do that ? Say I import my image how to I pass it into my array?

Comment: This would also be considered as a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674451/unable-to-load-images-dynamically-in-react-app

Comment: You need to narrow down a question and explicitly state the problem in the current example.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I am unsure what to ask. I did however find that I can just import an image a call it easily. I will update it as I get closer to figuring it out

Comment: Just state the problem instead. At the moment text does not contain it, therefore it is not clear how to help. Maybe you could say that images do not load, or when you click an image then view does not update, or else.

Comment: I see. I fixed my first issue! I did change my body, is it more apparent my issue? (new to stackoverlfow) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment all the values in the selected array are printed as plain text `<li key={index}>{t}</li>`, instead you could add some conditionals:

```
<ul>
  {clickedText.map((t, index) => {
    return index === 0 ? <li key={index}><img src={t} /></li> : <li key={index}>{t}</li>
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but this actually shows the image as the list item, I actually want it to not display at all. I may have worded my issue wrong. I want the first list item to not show at all. Thanks!

Comment: What if I wanted to not show the role name either just the description on click?

Comment: Nevermind I just added an or operator. (index === 0 || index === 1 !)

Comment: It would be easier if an `object` was used instead: `{"img":"...","label":"foo", "description": "bar"}` then you could do `<li>{clickedText.description}</li>`